# tictactoe: check for invalid input

Tags: c++

I'm building a tictactoe game in c++, and whenever users input a number that isn't 1-9, the output is supposed to be 'invalid move' and continue the game

```
else
    {
        cout << "Invalid move ";

        player--;
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    }
```

but it instead ends up generating the board repeatedly, and essentially breaking the game. Here is the full code:

```
    // This is a trial for tic tac toe in C++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char *squares = new char[9]{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

void play();
void getBoard();
int checkWin();

int main()
{
    char *playAgain = new char;
    do
    {
        play();
        cout << "Do you want to play again(y/n): ";
        cin >> *playAgain;

    } while (tolower(*playAgain) == 'y');
    delete squares, playAgain;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

//Play the game
void play()
{
    int *i = new int;
    int player = 1;
    int *choice = new int;
    char *mark = new char;

    do
    {
        getBoard();
        player = (player%2) ? 1 : 2;
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> *choice;
        *mark = (player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';

        if (squares[0] == '1' && *choice == 1)
        {
            squares[0] = *mark;
        }
        else if (squares[1] == '2' && *choice == 2)
        {
            squares[1] = *mark;
        }
        else if (squares[2] == '3' && *choice == 3)
        {
            squares[2] = *mark;
        }
        else if (squares[3] == '4' && *choice == 4)
        {
            squares[3] = *mark;
        }
        else if (squares[4] == '5' && *choice == 5)
        {
            squares[4] = *mark;
        }
        else if (squares[5] == '6' && *choice == 6)
        {
            squares[5] = *mark;
        }
        else if (squares[6] == '7' && *choice == 7)
        {
            squares[6] = *mark;
        }
        else if (squares[7] == '8' && *choice == 8)
        {
            squares[7] = *mark;
        }
        else if (squares[8] == '9' && *choice == 9)
        {
            squares[8] = *mark;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid move ";

            player--;
            cin.ignore();
            cin.get();
        }

        *i = checkWin();
        player++;

    } while (*i == -1);
    getBoard();
    if (*i == 1)
    {
        cout << "\aPlayer " << --player << " Wins" << endl;
        delete mark, choice, i;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\aGame Draw" << endl;
        delete mark, choice, i;
    }
}

// Print the board
void getBoard()
{
    cout << "\n\n\tTic Tac Toe\n\n";

    cout << "Player 1 (X)  -  Player 2 (O)" << endl
         << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << squares[0] << "  |  " << squares[1] << "  |  " << squares[2] << endl;

    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;

    cout << "  " << squares[3] << "  |  " << squares[4] << "  |  " << squares[5] << endl;

    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;

    cout << "  " << squares[6] << "  |  " << squares[7] << "  |  " << squares[8] << endl;

    cout << "     |     |     " << endl
         << endl;
}

/**********************************************************************************************************
Return 1 if some one wins
Return 0 if draw
Return -1 if the game is not over
***********************************************************************************************************/

int checkWin()
{
    if (squares[0] == squares[1] && squares[1] == squares[2])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (squares[0] == squares[3] && squares[3] == squares[6])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (squares[0] == squares[4] && squares[4] == squares[8])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (squares[3] == squares[4] && squares[4] == squares[5])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (squares[1] == squares[4] && squares[4] == squares[7])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (squares[6] == squares[4] && squares[4] == squares[2])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (squares[6] == squares[7] && squares[7] == squares[8])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (squares[2] == squares[5] && squares[5] == squares[8])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (squares[0] != '1' && squares[1] != '2' && squares[2] != '3' && squares[3] != '4' && squares[4] != '5' && squares[5] != '6' && squares[6] != '7' && squares[7] != '8' && squares[8] != '9')
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

How do I resolve this?

ps: any tips on improving the game logic would also be appreciated

Comment: You are a Java programmer learning C++, aren't you.

Comment: @paddy is it that obvious?

Comment: Yes.  You must ditch the habit of using `new` for everything and learn the difference between stack and heap allocation.  All this pointer indirection clutters your code and makes it unreadable, not to mention more prone to bugs.  Regarding your input, using `cin.ignore()` with `cin.get()` is not very robust.  You have no idea how many invalid characters they input, and which ones to ignore.  A simple solution is to just expect a line of input instead of reading an `int`.  Use `std::getline` and parse the value with a stringstream or `std::stoi`.

Comment: @timmyadolf, it hurts my brain to read your code. Yes, it is obvious :)

Comment: As a general note, use loops or variables to avoid code repetition.  `if (*choice >= 1 && *choice <= 9) { squares[*choice - 1] = *mark; }` would be sufficient

Comment: Your posted code has compiler errors. How did you even test it?

Comment: @RSahu it runs in both my compiler and online IDEs

Comment: This deletes `squares` and `playAgain` will leak: `delete squares, playAgain;` ... forget about `new` / `delete` for now. If you're using `g++` you could compile with `-g -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak -fstack-check` to get help with detecting stuff like this.